# When i am running my program Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:con.mysql.jdbc.driver error coming

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

[image]
For front end i am using Netbeans IDE 8.2
For back end SqlYog

[image]

I have pasted the jar file called Mysql connector still its not working any solution.

It is an runtime error. when i press login button then the error comes

Comment: Please paste code or error messages directly as text, instead of photographing your screen. That helps others to better read and understand your situation.

Comment: You don't need to do the "fashion tilt" when you photograph an error message. This isn't Instagram.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the jar to the classpath when starting your program like `java -cp mysql-connector-java.jar MyMain`

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar to your classpath